# T110 - Raid 1 - Rebuilding remains at 0% after switching from 1 hd

Tags: dell, raid1, dell-perc

Dell T 100 Server
PERC S 100 Controller
Raid 1 with 2 Hds

```
Physical Disks
 
ID 0: 0
Status OK
Name Physical Disk 0: 0
State Online
Bus Protocol SATA
Media HDD
Revision 02.03B05
Failure Predicted No
Capacity 232.75GB
Used RAID Disk Space 232.75GB
Available RAID Disk Space 0.00GB
Hot Spare No
Vendor ID DELL
Product ID WDC WD2502ABYS-18B7A0
Serial No. WD-WCAT1H763231
SAS Address 353FD0FD7EBA6B29
  
Physical Disk 0: 1 Online No Task Available SATA HDD 02.03B05
At the Physical Disks
 
ID 0: 1
Status OK
Name Physical Disk 0: 1
State Online
Bus Protocol SATA
Media HDD
Revision 02.03B05
Failure Predicted No
Capacity 232.75GB
Used RAID Disk Space 232.75GB
Available RAID Disk Space 0.00GB
Hot Spare No
Vendor ID DELL
Product ID WDC WD2502ABYS-18B7A0
Serial No. WD-WCAT1H357677
SAS Address 4AB5A5ED3C99B1EB
```

HD 0:1 presented error and was replaced by another identical, as     informed above, After the exchange it was triggered to the raid and requested the rebuilding however the rebuilding remains at 0% and does not advance.

[image: Rebuilding 0%]